# VSTS hosted build fails after upgrading to VS2017

Tags: tfs, asp.net-core, azure-devops, visual-studio-2017, azure-pipelines

I've upgraded asp.net core project (project.json) originally created in VS2015 to VS2017 MSBuild project format (.csproj).

Build definitions looks like this:

[image: build definition]

`Restore`, `Build` and `Test` build steps end up with follwong warning:

> Project file(s) matching the specified pattern were not found.

`Publish` build step ends with following error:

> MyProject.csproj' does not contain a project.json file

Is it because the hosted build agent was not updated yet? What can I do about it? When will it be?

Comment: this is related: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/3311

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [latest update](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/news/2017/mar-08-team-services#net-core-tasks-support-project-files) mentions that .NET Core tasks have been updated to support `.csproj` project system as well as `project.json`.

It's been more than 10 days since the announcement.However, there's a note at the top of the page

> Note: The features discussed in this post will be rolling out over the next three weeks.

Your tenant might be updated in the near future.

Comment: You might want to work this into your answer: https://twitter.com/tfsbuck/status/842471613278883840

Comment: @DaveShaw good point, I didn't know a separate agent was built for VS2017 support.

Comment: It might only be during the migration phase, I don't know the details. It still hasn't shown up on my VSTS account yet.

Comment: Ok, I had to do 3 manual steps in order to fix the build:
1. Go to build definition -> Edit -> options -> change agent queue to Hosted VS2017
2. For each .NET Core build step, edit `**/project.json` pattern to `**/*.csproj`
3. Remove `<Exec Command="bower install" />` command from .csproj PrepublishScript

Answer (score 1):

As [mentioned by Liero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42842656/vsts-hosted-build-fails-after-upgrading-to-vs2017#comment73080205_42845334), you need to update your builds to use the `Hosted VS2017` queue by editing the defintion and setting this appropriately on the Options tab.