# ##[error]Project file(s) matching the specified pattern were not found

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am having problems with a build pipeline.

[image: Pipeline]

[image: Get Sources]

The agent pools is hosted VS2017

The YAML is

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'VS2017-Win2016'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Debug'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk 2.1.5'
  inputs:
    version: 2.1.403


- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore
  inputs:
    command: restore

    projects: '**/Api*.csproj'


#Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘Parameters.projects’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972
#Your build pipeline references the ‘BuildConfiguration’ variable, which you’ve selected to be settable at queue time. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab, and then select the option to make it settable at queue time. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865971
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    projects: '$(Parameters.projects)'

    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'


#Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘Parameters.projects’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972
#Your build pipeline references the ‘BuildConfiguration’ variable, which you’ve selected to be settable at queue time. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab, and then select the option to make it settable at queue time. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865971

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish

    publishWebProjects: false

    projects: '$(Parameters.projects)'

    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
```

When it runs, the build task has the following log

```
2018-10-29T18:28:43.7087338Z ##[section]Starting: Build
2018-10-29T18:28:43.7093502Z ==============================================================================
2018-10-29T18:28:43.7093580Z Task         : .NET Core
2018-10-29T18:28:43.7093785Z Description  : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command. For package commands, supports NuGet.org and authenticated feeds like Package Management and MyGet.
2018-10-29T18:28:43.7093818Z Version      : 2.141.0
2018-10-29T18:28:43.7093864Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-10-29T18:28:43.7093895Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=832194)
2018-10-29T18:28:43.7093925Z ==============================================================================
2018-10-29T18:28:44.4833128Z [command]C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
2018-10-29T18:28:44.4926077Z Active code page: 65001
2018-10-29T18:28:45.1965225Z ##[error]Project file(s) matching the specified pattern were not found.
2018-10-29T18:28:45.2037015Z ##[section]Finishing: Build
```

I note that the log refers to 2.141.0  where as I am restoring the latest SDK 2.1.403  Why would that be? Could it be that the hosted VS2017 agent does not support the latest version of .netcore?

[Update]

I added a variable for Parameters.projects
[image: parameters projects]

However the build task has an error still.

```
2018-10-29T21:07:38.6774331Z ##[section]Starting: Build
2018-10-29T21:07:38.6781540Z ==============================================================================
2018-10-29T21:07:38.6781632Z Task         : .NET Core
2018-10-29T21:07:38.6781676Z Description  : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command. For package commands, supports NuGet.org and authenticated feeds like Package Management and MyGet.
2018-10-29T21:07:38.6781762Z Version      : 2.141.0
2018-10-29T21:07:38.6781807Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-10-29T21:07:38.6781853Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=832194)
2018-10-29T21:07:38.6781915Z ==============================================================================
2018-10-29T21:07:39.5030735Z [command]C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
2018-10-29T21:07:39.5157531Z Active code page: 65001
2018-10-29T21:07:39.5840366Z ##[error]Project file(s) matching the specified pattern were not found.
2018-10-29T21:07:39.5916864Z ##[section]Finishing: Build
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42842656/vsts-hosted-build-fails-after-upgrading-to-vs2017

Comment: Do you put value in the variable `$(Parameters.projects)`?

Comment: No. How do I do that?

Comment: looks like I missed pasting in the YAML to set up the Agent?

Comment: the build fails only in the build task, please see my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define in the build task which `.csproj` files you want to build.

In your case, the definition is in a variable `$(Parameters.projects)`.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    projects: '$(Parameters.projects)'

    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'
```

You can replace this variable in your `.csproj` (e.g. **/*.csproj for all .csproj files in all subfolders):

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    projects: '**/*.csproj'

    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'
```

Or go to the variables tab and add the `Parameters.projects` variable:

[image]

Comment: remove the '...' from the variable. `**/*.csproj` not `'**/*.csproj'`

Comment: This works but bad answer. I need a specific project path.

Comment: @DarthVader What do you mean? can you explain more?

Comment: Apparently not :'D

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk your hint about removing the single quotes helped me a lot! I have been deploying pipelines on YAML files with the single quotes on all paths, having had weird problems and thus having to do crazy trial and error attempts when it clearly should work since my first attempt... I see now that for situations where I have multiple paths, for example in a .NET Core CLI build task with multiple build paths in multiple lines, it is not necessary to insert the quotes, and the results are in fact unexpected when the quotes are there

Answer (score 14):

Posting just in case this helps anyone in the future

I had my `vmImage` set as `ubuntu` with the following set:

```
projects: '**\*.csproj'
```

The backslash was throwing things off, I had to switch to the following:

```
projects: '**/*.csproj'
```

I copied from a guide that was assuming Windows. Subtle enough, it took me a while to notice

Comment: Thanks for posting this @jack-casey I was facing the reverse of this issue (Building on Windows, but copied from a Linux guide)

Comment: switching to  backslash to forwards lash works for me in ubuntu.

Comment: You also need to make sure you get the case correct if you are running on Linux

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to build and publish a multiproject solution in dotnet core.
The solution structure is:

```
sampleTest.API
      sampleTest.API.csproj
sampleTest.Data
      sampleTest.Data.csproj
sampleTest.Identity
      sampleTest.Identity.csproj
sampleTest.Web
      sampleTest.Web.csproj
sampleTest.sln
```

Now, I just want to build the sampleTest.API dotnet core project. I just need to define in the build task, the path to the project as shown below.

The yaml file for build task for the pipeline in Azure Deveops is shown below:

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    projects: 'sampleTest.API/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'
```

If we need to build based on searching for all the 'cs.proj' files - we do

```
projects: '**/*.csproj'
```

Sample build task using the classic Editor in Azure Devops is shown below:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same error, But in my case I was making a very fundamental mistake that I didn't commit my project itself to git.

I just added my project and then run the pipeline, it worked.